# What's wrong with this groovy code line?

Tags: java, syntax, groovy

My IDE marks this line as being incorrect and missing **;** or **}** but I can't figure out whats actually wrong.

```
Class class // was assigned before
boolean implements = someClass.getInterfaces().any { item -> item.getName() == clazz?.name}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps it's because `implements` is a keyword? Try using a different variable name.

Answer (score 1):

"implements" seems to be a keyword. Have you tried changing the boolean name?

Comment: No problem. Everybody does this sometimes :P

Comment: Sorry, but the "glorry" should go to John, as he was first, but thank you a lot!